# What is the definition of a linear function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm curious what the definition of a linear function really is? I always hear that a linear function is a "straight line." That really isn't a definition- just a result.

Based on the real definition, how is an inversely proportional function not linear (i.e. $y=(a/x)$?

Comment: A linear function is one that satisfies $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$, for all appropriate scalars $\lambda$,  and $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$. This presupposes that $\lambda x$ and $x+y$ make sense, of course. People often use the term linear for an affine function (constant plus a linear function). I'm not sure what you meant by an 'inversely proportional function'.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the inversely proportional function - wrote it wrong the first time.

Comment: $\frac{a}{2x} \neq 2 \frac{a}{x}$. So $f(2x) \neq 2 f(x)$.

Comment: For avoiding of any confusion, always think about what's the domain and range of your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f$ is linear iff $f(ax)=af(x)$ and $f(x+y) =f(x) + f(y)$. This is sometimes written as one rule in the form: $$f(ax + by) = af(x)+bf(y)$$

A line has the property, so do planes. I don't know if you've studied calculus but even the derivative is linear: $$\frac{d}{dx}(af(x)+bg(x))=af'(x)+bf'(x)$$

Comment: In precalc a function is often defined as linear if it can be written in the form $f(x)=mx+b$.  But the definition in the  comments and the answers above are always used in more advanced math.